# windows10 のEdgeで戻るボタンを押下した後、前のページで２バイト文字が文字化けします

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

■環境
OS:　windows10　Home　64ビット
ブラウザ：edge
開発言語：asp dotnet, C#, MVC4
windows10 のEdgeのみ発生

■再現手順
windows10 のEdgeで
1. サイトにログイン
2. 任意リンクを押下して、任意ページに移動
3. windows10 のEdgeの「戻る」ボタンを押下する

■問題発生
　・「戻る」ボタンを押下すると、２バイト文字が文字化けしまう

蟷ｴ蠎ｦ・�  
譁・ｭ励し繧､繧ｺ・� 
蟆�
荳ｭ
螟ｧ
繝ｭ繧ｰ繧｢繧ｦ繝�縲|縲TEL: 012-345-6789

・Refreshすると、元々文字が表示される（文字化け発生なし）

年度：  
文字サイズ： 
小
中
大
ログアウト　|　TEL: 012-345-6789

■備考
　・この現象は、全てのページで起きています。
　・タイトルバーのテキストも起きています。

---

ご対応方法教えていただけませんか。
anhtuanpham2106@gmail.com

Comment: 個人情報にあたるものが書かれていますが大丈夫でしょうか。

Comment: @PlaTuan Windows の build 番号を追記して下さいませんか？

Comment: Yuki Inoue さんがご対応下さった結果、モデレーターによって個人情報のような部分は編集されました。